# Get DNS information with Windows API

Tags: windows, winapi, dns

I am having a problem trying to get DNS information with Windows API. I'm having a project that needs these DNS information:

```
<Host>scontent-hkg4-1.xx.fbcdn.net</Host>
<RecordName>scontent-hkg4-1.xx.fbcdn.net</RecordName>
<RecordType>A</RecordType>
<TimeToLive>PT6S</TimeToLive>
<DataLength>4</DataLength>
<RecordData>
   <IPv4Address>157.240.199.15</IPv4Address>
</RecordData>
```

This project doesn't allow me to use cmd to get information from ipconfig, so can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: This sounds like homework

Comment: @Keltari No, I'm doing a forensics tool using python for my graduation internship. This is the last volatile information that I can't find the API needed to access.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of Windows APIs available for DNS management in `windns.h` header file. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_dns/).

Or without using any of `ipconfig` or Windows APIs you can use .NET framework class `System.Net.Dns`. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns?view=netcore-3.1)